# SQL Server Version Error with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I built a simple website, it's like a watered down directory. You list all `entries` and then can click on an entry to know more details.

It works fine on my test server, but swapped over to another server it breaks. I am unsure why exactly, and I have not altered the code from the working code. So I assume that it is a version error.

However I am unsure what, and therefore can't think of alternative ways to write it.

Here is the sample of code causing problems:

```
$username456 = 'username';
$password456 = 'password';

$entryid = $_POST['entryid'];


$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=hostaddress;dbname=dbname', $username456, $password456);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$tlo = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entryID = {$entryid} ");
$tlo->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $tlo->fetch()) {

 //loop stuff

}
```

I don't see how it's different from the code working on another page, however this is the error I keep getting thrown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in /homepages/11/d211013232/htdocs/WEBSITE/entry.php:54 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/11/d211013232/htdocs/WEBSITE/entry.php(54): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM e...') #1 {main} thrown in /homepages/11/d211013232/htdocs/WEBSITE/entry.php on line 54
```

Anyone know what it might be?

Comment: Just for fun, try `WHERE entryID = '$entryid'");` or `WHERE entryID = '".$entryid."'");`

Comment: SQL INJECTION WARNING!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the curly brackets around $entryid, and you need to close the string before concatenating variables:

```
$tlo = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entryID = '" $entryid "' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
$tlo = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entryID = {$entryid} ");
```

to this

```
$tlo = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `entries` WHERE entryID = '$entryid'");
```